# laravel 9 Redirection problem instead of going to /home redirecting to /login

Tags: database, redirect

LoginController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
class LoginController extends Controller
{
use AuthenticatesUsers;
public function login()
{
$user = request()->only(['email','password']);

if (Auth::attempt($user))
{
$user = Auth::user();
$teachers = Teacher::latest()->get();
echo "dvjkhgf";
return redirect()-\>intended('home');//,compact('teachers'));
```

}
}

my web.php:

```
Route::get('/login', function () {
return redirect('/login');});

Auth::routes();
Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
```

on submit it is taking me to /login not home view. i has home .blade on path.
using web hosting plateform not localhost.

i tried all check of web.php, no duplicates in web.php